# Error: "System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. " How to fix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1

This exception has been thrown when I try run my ASP.NET Core application:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.VerifyServicesRegistered(IApplicationBuilder app)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.UseAuthorization(IApplicationBuilder app)
> at API.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in /Users/fathindosunmu/OneDrive/MyProjects/GitHubProjects/Reactivities/Reactivities/WebAPI/Startup.cs:line 164
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.VerifyServicesRegistered(IApplicationBuilder app)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.UseAuthorization(IApplicationBuilder app)
> at API.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in /Users/fathindosunmu/OneDrive/MyProjects/GitHubProjects/Reactivities/Reactivities/WebAPI/Startup.cs:line 164
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
> at API.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/fathindosunmu/OneDrive/MyProjects/GitHubProjects/Reactivities/Reactivities/WebAPI/Program.cs:line 16

Even though I have registered all required services in `configureServices` method (see the registrations just below). Why is this exception being thrown if `AddAuthorization` is called explicitly?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("MsSqlConnection"));
    });

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsAllowAll",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                builder.WithExposedHeaders("WWW-Authenticate");
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                builder.AllowCredentials();
            });
    });

    services.AddMediatR(typeof(List.Handler).Assembly);
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(List.Handler));
    services.AddSignalR();

    var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>();
    var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
    identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
    identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("IsActivityHost", policy =>
        {
            policy.Requirements.Add(new IsHostRequirement());
        });
    });
    services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, IsHostRequirementHandler>();


    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:SigningKey"]));
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).
        AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = key,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    //receiving jwt token as a request header from client because the chatHub is not a HTTP request
                    //Protocol
                    var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                    var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && (path.StartsWithSegments("/chat")))
                    {
                        context.Token = accessToken;
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });

    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

    }).AddFluentValidation(config =>
        config.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Create>());

    services.AddScoped<IJWTGenerator, JWTGenerator>();
    services.AddScoped<IUserAccessor, UserAccessor>();
    services.AddScoped<IPhotoAccessor, PhotoAccessor>();
    services.AddScoped<IProfileReader, ProfileReader>();
    services.Configure<CloudinarySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Cloudinary"));
}
```

I have searched everywhere for a hint on what could be the problem, but I can't find the solution.

Comment: Have you tried to run your application locally without **Authorization**?

Comment: I still get the nasty exceptions being thrown @PeterCsala

Comment: And in that case is it still referring to the `AddAuthorization`?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the tag with the relevant version of ASP.NET Core you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below line AddAuthorization() as below.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.ConfigureIdentity();
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely forgot to call `app.UseAuthorization()` in your `Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` method. [From the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/16a47948f80fede807fabe3c291d793590e8fd17/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.cs#L35):

```
// Verify that AddAuthorizationPolicy was called before calling UseAuthorization
// We use the AuthorizationPolicyMarkerService to ensure all the services were added.
if (app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(AuthorizationPolicyMarkerService)) == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.FormatException_UnableToFindServices(
        nameof(IServiceCollection),
        nameof(PolicyServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAuthorization),
        "ConfigureServices(...)"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, see your nuget packages and then retart your visual studio code your NuGet packages may not have installed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

check if you forgot or mistakenly deleted Controller in Startup File

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```